# IBM domino People view column data does not reflect document data

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, notesview

Inn IBM Domino, Document fields of person is created and updated programmatically. 
The program that creates the document does subsequent updates and the updated fields are not visible in the "People View" of IBM Domino.

However, the data in the document is as expected with the correct seq. num in the field propertis.

I am new to Domino and as of now clueless. I really appreciate any help here.

Thanks ,
Karthik

Comment: Sometimes, the informations displayed into view columns are calculated based on other fields. Please give us the list of updated fields and the list of columns where you want to see these data.

Answer (score 1):

The view is probably broken. Rebuild it with SHIFT-F9 in Notes client or
run `Load updall names.nsf -R` on server console.

Answer (score 0):

(Five years later)... You must set NotesItems (fields) created programmatically (by LotusScript/Java/COM) to have a 'summary' flag. The flag is set by the 'IsSummary' property of the NotesItem. For example, in LotusScript:

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim item As NotesItem
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set doc = New NotesDocument( db )
Set item = New NotesItem(doc, "FldName", "My new value" )
item.IsSummary = True '<<< must specifically set this property true
Call doc.Save( False, True )
```

If this flag isn't set, the field will not be considered 'indexable' by the view builder.

*(PS: This is 'normal behaviour' - forget F9 view rebuilds, although it won't hurt, it won't solve the issue).*